# How can you integrate a variable in a JSON path in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

First of all, it's connecting to a url and just sanitizing it all in the Front-End. The Hypixel API works so, that you take the api url for the wanted request, in this case api.hypixel.net/player?name=USERNAME&key=APIKEY, and get back a big JSON file, which my code should sanitize. So, if you're using the Hypixel API, yeah you're sending the API-Key through the browser, but that is a security flaw in the Hypixle API and not in my code. The sole purpose of my code is to learn more about JavaScript an show it to others.

I'm working on an API access to the Hypixel API.
This gets me a JSON, in which I want to get a specific game, that was inputted in a field an is saved in a dict.

I'm trying to integrate this like this (console.log is only for test purposes, until I give back the data to HTML):

```js
let values = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('#apiForm input'))
    .reduce((acc, input) => {
        return { ...acc, [input.id]: input.value };
    }, {})

fetch(`https://api.hypixel.net/player?name=${values.name}&key=${values.key}`)
    .then(result => result.json())
    .then(result => {
        if (result.success) {
            if (values.game in result.player.stats) {
                console.log(result.player.stats.$(values.game)) //not working
            } else {
                console.log(result.player.stats)
                console.log('Game not available or not played yet')
            }
        } else {
            console.log('Something went wrong, please check your name and API-Key or try again later')
        }
    })
```

How can I do this here?

The API-Form looks like this:
[image: Form]

And the JSON file looks like this:
[image: JSON file]

So when I input Bedwars for example, the path I want should result in `result.player.stats.Bedwars`:

Comment: Which part of this isn't working exactly? What does the HTML for your input fields look like?

Comment: `result.player.stats.$(values.game)` this loc looks suspicious. You have just deserialized object from json and expecting it to have some `$` function.

Comment: Hold up. You're not planning on having users enter an API key you've had generated for your app, are you? Those should be kept secret, serverside, not passed around and entered in the browser.

Comment: @DustInCompetent Nope, it's connecting to a url and just sanitizing it all in the Front-End. The Hypixel API works so, that you take the api url for the wanted request, in this case https://api.hypixel.net/player?name=USERNAME&key=APIKEY, and get back a big JSON file, which my code should sanitize. So, if you're using the Hypixel API, yeah you're sending the API-Key through the browser, but that is a security flaw in the Hypixle API and not in my code. The sole purpose of my code is to learn more about JavaScript an show it to others.

Comment: It's not a flaw in the API, most APIs need you to send some sort of key with any request, but that should be done without the users needing to know the key. Normally, you'd keep the key secret on the application server that serves your website, and requests are made from the site to the server, which then makes the API request.

Comment: The API-Key needs to be generated by the user on the Minecraft server, so it can't know I before. Also the user can generate new ones, leading to the old ones not working anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `result.player.stats.$(values.game)` with

```js
result.player.stats[values.game]
```

Also, when putting user input into URI paths, sanitize it with `encodeURIComponent` or build the query string with new `URLSearchParams({ ...props }).toString()`.